# Issue in regex for a valid format

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I am adding a restriction on string using the regex pattern matching but it is not working as i have not much experience in regex.
Like there can't be no ( without ) or [ without ].

```
abc.(%      -->false
abc.)%      -->false
abc.(%]     -->false
abc.)%]     -->false
1abc9.(%[   -->false
abc.)%[     -->false
abc.(%(     -->false
abc.)%)     -->false
19.(%)%     -->true
19.[%]%     -->true
2009% --> true
19.1245 -- true 
10.[5-9]% -- true
```

```sh
/^[^\s\[\]^$.|A-Z]*(?:(?:\[[^\s\[\]\\]+](?!\])|%[^\r\n\?\$\*\.\[\+\(\)\]\.\^%]+%(?=\||$)|\|[^\s\[\]^A-Z\\]+)[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*)*$/

The string is fine if it have start with ( and end with )
19[1-3] is fine
2014.56(core) is fine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go about this using a whitelist of what is allowed, rather than trying to run around and cover every negative case.  That is, use the following regex pattern:

```
^\S+\.(?:(?:\(%\)|\[%\])%?)?$
```

### Demo

Some JS code:

```js
var valid = "19.(%)";
if (/^\S+\.(?:(?:\(%\)|\[%\])%?)?$/.test(valid)) {
    console.log("VALID:   " + valid);
}

var invalid = "abc.(%";
if (!/^\S+\.(?:(?:\(%\)|\[%\])%?)?$/.test(invalid)) {
    console.log("INVALID: " + invalid);
}
```

Comment: "19.(%)", 19(%)  these also need to be valid but it is not.
can you please help me in that

Comment: one last modification if possible.
19.12345 , 19.dada can this also be allowed ?

Comment: Please explore the regex demo for futher changes.  You never told us this positive case, so I won't edit my answer a third time.

Comment: I have updated the question if you would like to check.
Thanks